# Displaying the roots of a complex function using ListCurvePathPlot

Tags: plotting, complex

I have the following algorithm:

```
B[z_] = ((z*(z - 0.5)*(z + 0.5)*(z + 0.3))/((1 - 0.5*z)*(1 + 
          0.5*z)*(1 + 0.3*z))) // Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify;
For[n = 1, n < 5, n++, 
    roots = {Re[z], Im[z]} /. Solve[B[z] == (I^n), z]; 
    g[n_] := Plot[
       Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[8], {Lighter[Gray], Circle[]}, {Blue, 
          Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ roots}, 
         First@ListCurvePathPlot[roots, PlotStyle -> Blue], Frame -> True,
          FrameLabel -> {"Re[z]", "Im[z]"}, 
         PlotLabel -> ("Roots of " <> 
            ToString[B[z] == 1, TraditionalForm] <> "\n")}, 
        Axes -> True], {x, -2, +2}];
     Print[g[n]]]
```

The `For` loop is working, but I want to embed all of the graphics in one graphic.

Comment: You can try again using the function B[z_] = ((z*(z - 0.5)*(z + 0.5)*(z + 0.3))/((1 - 0.5*z)*(1 + 
          0.5*z)*(1 + 0.3*z))) // Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify;

Comment: Is it ok? I have tried show command but I couldnt

Answer (score 2):

```
B[z_] = ((z*(z - 0.5)*(z + 0.5)*(z + 0.3))/((1 - 0.5*z)*(1 + 0.5*z)*(1 + 
          0.3*z))) // Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify;
```

Note that n = 1 and n = 5 are equivalent so there are only four unique sets of roots

```
I^# & /@ Range[5]
```

> {I, -1, -I, 1, I}

```
roots = ({Re[z], Im[z]} /. Solve[B[z] == (I^#), z] & /@ Range[4]) // N;

ListCurvePathPlot[
 n = 0; Tooltip[#, "n = " <> ToString[n++]] & /@ roots,
 n =.;
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Re[z]", "Im[z]"}, 
 PlotLabel -> ("Roots of " <> ToString[B[z] == I^n, TraditionalForm] <> 
    "\n"),
 PlotRange -> 1.2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 Epilog -> {
   Lighter[Gray],
   Circle[],
   AbsolutePointSize[8],
   Table[{
     ColorData[1][n],
     Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ roots[[n]]},
    {n, 4}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
B[z_] = ((z*(z - 0.5)*(z + 0.5)*(z + 0.3))/((1 - 0.5*z)*(1 + 
     0.5*z)*(1 + 0.3*z))) // Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify

plots = {}; 
For[n = 1, n < 5, n++, roots = {Re[z], Im[z]} /. Solve[B[z] == (I^n), z];
 AppendTo[plots, 
   Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[8], {Lighter[Gray], Circle[]}, {Blue, 
      Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ roots}, 
     First@ListCurvePathPlot[roots, PlotStyle -> Blue]}, Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> {"Re[z]", "Im[z]"}, 
    PlotLabel -> ("Roots of " <> ToString[B[z] == 1, TraditionalForm] <> "\n"), 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, Automatic}]]]

Show[plots]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
B[z_] = ((z*(z - 0.5)*(z + 0.5)*(z + 0.3))/((1 - 0.5*z)*(1 + 0.5*z)*(1 + 0.3*z)));

res = Re[{Re[z], Im[z]} /. NSolve[B[z] == (I^#), z]] & /@ Range@5;

Show[ListCurvePathPlot[res, Axes -> True], 
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[8], {Lighter[Gray], Circle[]}, {Blue, 
    Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ res}}]]
```

[image]

The imaginary parts are zero everywhere, so we only need `Re`.